# I have a problem with my code how can I simplify it?

Tags: javascript

I am new at coding. My code is working but my question is how can I simplify and shorten my code given below:

```js
var age = 20;
var homme = '';
var femme = 'f';
var homme1 = homme.toUpperCase();
var femme1 = femme.toUpperCase();
var result = '';

if (typeof age == 'number' && (homme1 == 'H' || femme1 == 'F')) {
  if (age >= 20 && homme1 == 'H') {
    result = 'Age : ' + age + ', Sexe ' + homme1 + ', La personne est imposable';
  } else if (age >= 18 && age <= 35 && femme1 == 'F') {
    result = 'Age : ' + age + ', Sexe ' + femme1 + ', La personne est imposable';
  } else {
    result = 'Age : ' + age + ', Sexe ' + femme1 + ", La personne n'est pas imposable";
  }
} else {
  result = 'donnée erronée';
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: well, first thing comes to my mind that you dont need to double check `homme1` and `femme1`.  remove them in the first if condition. also this question should be asked in code review stack exchange site

Comment: This question should be asked at Code Review.

Comment: Based on that code the result will always be "donnée erronée".

Comment: @MichaelHaddad, the question needs work before it's suited to [codereview.se]. You should have pointed the asker at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. we need a good description of the *purpose* of the code to give context, and question titles should simply say what the code *does* (the question is always, "_How can I improve this?_").  It's important that the code works correctly; include the unit tests if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```js
// INPUTS
let age = 20, homme = "", femme = "f", result = "";

// VALIDATE
let homme1 = homme.toUpperCase();
let femme1 = femme.toUpperCase();

// CHECKS
let isNumber = typeof age == "number";
let isEitherGender = homme1 == "H" || femme1 == "F";
let isAgeAbove20 = age >= 20;
let isAgeAbove18 = age >= 18;
let isAgeLess35 = age >= 35;
let isHomme1H = homme1 == "H";
let isFemmel1F = homme1 == "F";

// LOGIC
if(isNumber && isEitherGender){
    if(isAgeAbove20 && isHomme1H){
        result = "Age : " + age + ", Sexe " + homme1 +  ", La personne est imposable";
    } else if(isAgeAbove18 && isAgeLess35 && isFemmel1F){
        result = "Age : " + age + ", Sexe " + femme1 +  ", La personne est imposable";
    } else{
        result = "Age : " + age + ", Sexe " + femme1 +  ", La personne n'est pas imposable";
    }
}else{
    result = "donnée erronée";
}
// OUTPUT
console.log(result);
```

else here is a minified version got it from [minifier.org](https://www.minifier.org/)

```js
let age=20,homme="",femme="f",result="";let homme1=homme.toUpperCase();let femme1=femme.toUpperCase();let isNumber=typeof age=="number";let isEitherGender=homme1=="H"||femme1=="F";let isAgeAbove20=age>=20;let isAgeAbove18=age>=18;let isAgeLess35=age>=35;let isHomme1H=homme1=="H";let isFemmel1F=homme1=="F";if(isNumber&&isEitherGender){if(isAgeAbove20&&isHomme1H){result="Age : "+age+", Sexe "+homme1+", La personne est imposable"}else if(isAgeAbove18&&isAgeLess35&&isFemmel1F){result="Age : "+age+", Sexe "+femme1+", La personne est imposable"}else{result="Age : "+age+", Sexe "+femme1+", La personne n'est pas imposable"}}else{result="donnée erronée"}
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
age =20;
var hommeOuFemme = "f".toUpperCase();
var result = "donnée erronée";

   if(typeof age == "number"){
    result = "Age : " + age + ", Sexe " + hommeOuFemme;
    if((age >= 20 && hommeOuFemme == "H") || (age >= 18 && age <=35 && hommeOuFemme == "F")){
        result += ", La personne est imposable";
    }else{
        result += ", La personne n'est pas imposable";
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Firstly, I recommend you to put both femme and homme in one variable since someone can check both of them at the same time

```
age = 20;
var homme = "h".toUpperCase();
var femme = "f".toUpperCase();
```

Output:

```
Age : 20, Sexe H, La personne est imposable
```

In the first if, you can check just the type of age since you will check the sexe after.
And if you want to optimize you can set the result to "donnée erronée" from the start because in case the first if won't be hit then you don't have to reinitialize result again. Also, if age is valid(a number) then you can set result to

```
result = "Age : " + age + ", Sexe " + hommeOuFemme;
```

and just concatenate the last part depending of each if block.